# HTML DOM PARSER

Tags: php, html

Имеется html код следующего вида

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как вытащить по отдельности поле 1, поле 2, поле 3 используя библиотеку [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
Вывожу вот так, работает не так как нужно

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/');
foreach($html->find('table tr td:nth-child(1)') as $row) {
    echo $row->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: покажите код в тегах <pre>

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Поправил описание вопроса.

Comment: покажите дамп переменной (массива) цикла

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, добавьте ссылку на библиотеку в вопрос

Answer (score 5):

Зачем вам `:nth-child(1)` в селекторе? Вот так в цикле выведет все ячейки всех строк во всех таблицах документа.

```
<?php
    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://localhost/');
    foreach($html->find('table tr td') as $row) {
        echo $row->plaintext;
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Вот куча примеров в [документации](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Например можно все ячейки только первой строке вывести:

```
<?php
    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://localhost/');
    foreach($html->find('table tr', 0) as $row) {
        foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
            echo $cell->plaintext;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

### UPD

Для получения только первой ячейки в таблице

```
$html->find('table tr td', 0)[0]->plaintext;
```

Для получения только первых ячеек во всех строках всех таблиц в документе

```
<?php
    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://localhost/');
    foreach($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
        foreach($row->find('td', 0) as $cell) { // 0 это кол-во требуемых элементов -1
            echo $cell->plaintext;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Он выводит все td, а мне к примеру из трех td нужен только самый первый

Comment: @ОнотолЕ вы документацию читали? Там же все написано простым языком с примерами конкретными. Обновил ответ