# Preg_match_all() PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
<dd class="message message fade"><ul><li>Время сессии истекло, пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь на сайте заново.</li></ul></dd>
```

Как с помощью PHP preg_match_all() достать содержимое тега li ?

Я не хочу использовать SIMPLE HTML DOM потому как он требует mbstring, ну и плюс медленнее, чем простое регулярное выражение.

Comment: Зачем all, если строка одна?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [HTML DOM PARSER](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471924/html-dom-parser)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew как он может быть дубликатом, когда тот вопрос был про конкретную библиотеку - а здесь ее-то и не хочется использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием [именованной подмаски](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

```
$subject = '<dd class="message message fade"><ul><li>Время сессии истекло, пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь на сайте заново.</li></ul></dd>';

preg_match_all('/<li>(?P<liContent>[^<]+)<\/li>/ui', $subject, $matches);

// результаты в массиве $matches['liContent']
var_dump($matches['liContent']);

// array(1) {
//   [0] =>
//   string(118) "Время сессии истекло, пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь на сайте заново."
// }
```

Comment: А если внутри элемента li встретится другой тег, как поведет себя ваша регулярка?

Comment: Если встретится, то человек узнает, что для сложных случаев лучше использовать какой-нибудь [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: В моей задаче другого li не встретится, там только два возможных варианта.

Comment: Не встречал в мануалах про такой способ раньше, огромное спасибо.

Comment: @xEdelweiss если несколько `<li>` и в каждой какое то свойсто а не фиксированное то регулярка не подойдет.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan именно так, но достаточно и одного `li` с атрибутом или лишним пробелом. С регуляркой проще работать до тех пор, пока имеется представление об исходной строке. Для всех случаев она не подойдет или будет слишком сложной.

Comment: @xEdelweiss Вот регулярка на все случаи жизни

`/<li>(?P<li((?!>).)*>[^<]+)<\/li>/ui`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan очень самоуверенно, но ваша "регулярка" не разберет даже пример из вопрос. Не используйте комментарии для публикации ответа.

Comment: @xEdelweiss ах да вы же две `<li>` добавили в начало регулярки, вот так точьно работает, и не важно какие параметры в теге `<li>` есть или их вообще нет `/(<li((?!>).)*>[^<]+)<\/li>/`

Comment: @xEdelweiss  можете проверить здесь и вашу и мою.
http://regexr.com